# Отображение элементов Simple_form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

В `simple_form` есть элемент `association`. Возникает проблема при попытке его отображения через *bootstrap 2*: сами чекбоксы или радиобатоны находятся на одной строке, а лайбл к ним на другой. Как бороться не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
= f.association :detraining,
    label: false,
    label_method: :description,
    collection: Detraining.order(:level),
    as: :radio_buttons,
    item_wrapper_tag: 'div'
```

Я так понимаю что `item_wrapper_tag: 'div'` это то что мне было нужно?

Comment: Добавьте кусочек шаблона, в котором выводится `association`